# Storyboard not found, ViewControllers Seques with modal

Tags: ios, swift

I have a LaunchScreen.storyboard and a Main.storyboard

Inside of my Main.storyboard, the main storyboard has my welcome screen. I have two other ViewControllers there.

The flow is Main(storyboard) -> ItemResults(VC) -> ItemSingleView(VC)

From main to one of the ViewControllers I do the following.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let itemResults = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemResults") as! ItemResultsViewController
itemResults.itemDescriptionData = self.itemDescription.text!
self.present(itemResults, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

This will take me from the Main to ItemResults as well as pass a String along. Inside of ItemResults(VC) I have a TableView. What I am looking to do is when you click on the cell, it gathers information from the cell, opens a modal and displays information in there pertaining to the cell that was clicked.

That seque looks like this

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ItemResults", bundle: nil)
let singleItemResult = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewSingleItem") as! ViewSingleItem 
singleItemResult.theItemID = selectedItem.itemID
self.present(singleItemResult, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I then get the following error.

> 'Could not find a storyboard named 'ItemResults' in bundle NSBundle

I know why I get the error, because ItemResults isn't a storyboard, its a VC. After doing research, I can use Storyboard Reference, but then I have to redesign my layouts..... and they weren't really fun to do.

Why is this a problem? In the second seque above, If I changed ItemResults to Main, it works, the problem is, when I click it, the modal shows up, but then the app displays the Main screen again, and it doesn't stay on ItemResults.

Can anyone help with this? Thanks!!

Adding didSelect

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
    tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let selectedItem = self.currentItemsArray[indexPath.row]
    print(selectedItem.itemID)
}
```

I "fixed" the issue by adding a seque in the storyboard from the tableview cell, to the new ViewController. I gave that Seque an ID and did the following method.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if  segue.identifier == "ShowItemDetailsSeque",
        let destination = segue.destination as? ViewSingleItem,
        let itemIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
    {
        let selectedItem = self.currentItemsArray[itemIndex]
        destination.theItemID = selectedItem.itemID
        print(selectedItem.itemTitle)

    }
}
```

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: It has to be Main for sure. Can you add didSelect method also ?

Comment: @SharadChauhan I added that information as well as a possible solution. Please take a look. If there is a better way, please let me know.

Comment: let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ItemResults", bundle: nil)
this line has mistake here name:"main"

Comment: @chiragshah please read everything above....i already discussed this, and the outcome, and why its not a good one.